# How to use a Jenkins Environment Variable as Input to a Plugin

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, octopus-deploy

I would like to set the release number for an Octopus Deploy release using the Jenkins build number.  In the OctopusDeploy Release plugin I have tried for the following in the release number field:

```
 1.0.%BUILD_NUMBER%
```

and

```
 1.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

The variable is not replaced with it's value and I get an error like this:

> The release number '1.0.%BUILD_NUMBER%' does not appear to be a valid semantic version number. At a minimum, release numbers require at least two parts, such as '1.3'.

It seems the above conventions only work as inputs in scripts.  How can I refer to the build number as input in a plugin field?

Comment: Have you tried to use BUILD_NUMBER variable without any prefixes? Is it passed or you're still seeing variable as name? Maybe plugin itself uses different syntax to refer to standard variables?

Comment: @Mikhail I wound up using a powershell task.  Is there a standard for how plugins deal with variables in Jenkins?  I would expect using the variable name without some token would be problematic

Answer (score 0):

For powershell install powershell plugin into jenkins, then add Windows Powershell step, below you may see link:

[image: jenkins.png]

It will redirect you to the page with standard variables, in order to get build number variable you refer to it as described on that page, i.e.:

```
$env:BUILD_NUMBER
```

Also, I would recommend creating powershell variable before passing it to smwhere else, in your case it should look like this:

```
$var="1.0." + $env:BUILD_NUMBER
```

You may check variable before passing it any further by calling echo:

```
echo $var
```

Also, windows have powerful built-in tool that could help you write your powershell scripts: Windows Powershell ISE